# Bash - Fill with 0 every number to make it 4 digits using sed

Tags: bash, sed, numbers, addition, zero

I have tried different ways of doing this. I need to transform this:

> 5 dias, 3 meses, 4 anos
>
> 67 decimales
>
> naranjas 45, limones 56
>
> 66 + 44 = 100.
>
> 7777a 7b 88c 777d

Into this:

> 0005 dias, 0003 meses, 0004 anos
>
> 0067 decimales
>
> naranjas 0045, limones 0056
>
> 0066 + 0044 = 0100.
>
> 7777a 0007b 0088c 0777d

But I cannot manage to add zeros to the last line with the code I have so far, which is the following:

```
sed -e 's/\b[0-9]\{3\}\b/0&/g; s/\b[0-9]\{2\}\b/00&/g; s/\b[0-9]\b/000&/g' numbers.txt >output.txt
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You should be using `[^0-9]` instead of `\b`, since the letters are not word breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use perl

```
perl -pe 's/\d+/sprintf "%04d",$&/ge' test
```

or if you really want to use sed

```
sed -r ':1;s/([^0-9]|^)([0-9]{1,3})([^0-9]|$)/\10\2\3/;t1' file
```